# When and from where was the PAC first legally defined

Tags: united-states, terminology, campaign-finance, fec

The FEC explains the different types of political action committees (PACs) but did Congress legally define what a PAC is? I'm assuming that the FEC didn't legally define what a PAC is since it is a regulatory agency and doesn't create the laws. Did the Federal Election Campaign Act (FECA) created by Congress in 1971 define what a PAC is? I can't find any information on it.

Comment: While they can't make new laws often times the law itself doesn't spell everything out (though in this case they did define what a PAC was, as the checked answer says).  Traditionally the courts have given agencies what's known as chevron deference to carry out the law and make interpretations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevron_U.S.A.,_Inc._v._Natural_Resources_Defense_Council,_Inc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Did the Federal Election Campaign Act (FECA) created by Congress in 1971 define what a PAC is?*

Yes. The definition is in [Section 301](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/STATUTE-86/pdf/STATUTE-86-Pg3.pdf#page=9) as:

> (d) "political committee" means any committee, association,
> or organization which accepts contributions or makes expenditures during a calendar year in an aggregate amount exceeding $1,000;

Additional definitions include "contribution" and "expenditure".

---

The current definition for "political committee" is in [52 U.S. Code § 30101](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/52/30101) - Definitions:

> (4)The term “political committee” means—
>
> > (A) any committee, club, association, or other group of persons which receives contributions aggregating in excess of $1,000 during a calendar year or which makes expenditures aggregating in excess of $1,000 during a calendar year; or
> >
> > (B) any separate segregated fund established under the provisions of section 30118(b) of this title; or
> >
> > (C) any local committee of a political party which receives contributions aggregating in excess of $5,000 during a calendar year, or makes payments exempted from the definition of contribution or expenditure as defined in paragraphs (8) and (9) aggregating in excess of $5,000 during a calendar year, or makes contributions aggregating in excess of $1,000 during a calendar year or makes expenditures aggregating in excess of $1,000 during a calendar year.